# Reduce Array of Tuples

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, mapreduce

I have an array of Tuples:

```
var baseItems = [(item: Item, amount: Float)]
```

In this array there may be 2 or more identical `Item` with different `amount`. I want to reduce this `baseItems` Array to only contain unique `Item`s and add up their `amount`.

Here is an example:

```
baseItems = [(Wood, amount: 10), (Metal, amount: 5), (Wood, amount: 3)]
```

should be transformed into:

```
baseItems = [(Wood, amount: 13), (Metal, amount: 5)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let baseItems = [(wood, amount: 10), (metal, amount: 5), (wood, amount: 3)]
var newArray: [(Item, Float)] = []

// One line
Set(baseItems.map { $0.0 }).forEach { base in newArray += [(base, baseItems.filter { $0.0 == base }.reduce(0) { $0 + Float($1.1) })] }

print(newArray) // [(Wood, amount: 13), (Metal, amount: 5)]
```

Something like this. Could still be made a bit more elegant.

UPDATE:

```
class Item: Hashable {
    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    var hashValue: Int { return name.hashValue }
}

func ==(lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}

let woods = Item(name: "Woods")
let metal = Item(name: "Metal")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is probably what I am looking for. Though I can't get it to work, since It is not [(String, Int)] but [(Item, Float)]. I get the error  Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Set<_>' with an argument list of type '([Item])'. I did manage to get an filtered [(id: Int, amount: Float)] Array back, and have a method to get to proper Item from an id, but I feel this is more like a tacky thing to do

Comment: Yea I changed it to a string so it was easier to test things out. You'll have to change your class `Item` to conform the protocol `Hashable` so it works with `Set`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce over a dictionary with key being the item, and value the sum of amounts for that item, and after that get back to an array of tuples:

```
let baseItems = [(item: "Wood", amount: 10), (item: "Metal", amount: 5), (item: "Wood", amount: 3)]
let normalizedItems = baseItems.reduce([String:Int]()) {
    var dict = $0
    dict[$1.item] = (dict[$1.item] ?? 0) + $1.amount
    return dict
    }.map{$0}
```

or, in one line:

```
let normalizedItems = baseItems.reduce([String:Int]()) { var d = $0; d[$1.item] = (d[$1.item] ?? 0) + $1.amount; return d }.map{$0}
```

**Note.** I assumed that the item is a `String`, and the amount is an `Int`, but this works with any other type, as long as the item is `Hashable` and can be used as a key for the dictionary.